# converting a date in format dd-MMM-YYYY to date or dd/mm/yyyy format in JS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datepicker

I need to convert date displayed in dd-MMM-YYYY or dd/mm/yyyy(both format possible) to normal milli seconds in JavaScrpit. I was initially using datePicker but that does not support the format dd-MMM-YYYY . Is there any other way of doing this without using moment.js ?

code I have used:

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var map = {
            Jan: 0, Feb: 1, Mar: 2, Apr: 3, May: 4, Jun: 5,
            Jul: 6, Aug: 7, Sep: 8, Oct: 9, Nov: 10, Dec: 11
            };
  input = input.split('-');
  return (new Date(input[2], map[input[1]], input[0]));
}
```

Comment: I have written a function to parse the date in case it is in format dd-MMM-YYYY . But I am looking if there is a better way for doing this.

Comment: suggesting and helping would be easy if you share code you have tried.

Comment: code added for the part where I am parsing date in format dd-MMM-YYYY

Comment: You could replace your small function with a few thousand lines of moment.js, but why? Parsing dd/mm/yyyy is even simpler. You could include both formats in your function using `split(/[-\/]/)` and `map[input[1]] || input[1] - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
function parseDate(input) {
      var map = {jan: 1, feb: 2, mar: 3, apr: 4, may: 5, jun: 6,
                 jul: 7, aug: 8, sep: 9, oct: 10, nov: 11, dec: 12};
      input = input.split(/[-\/]/);
      alert(map[input[1].toLowerCase()]);
      return new Date(input[2], (map[input[1].toLowerCase()] || input[1]) - 1, input[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify the parsing function to handle dd-mmm-yyyy and d/m/y:

```js
function parseDate(input) {
  var map = {Jan: 0, Feb: 1, Mar: 2, Apr: 3, May: 4, Jun: 5,
             Jul: 6, Aug: 7, Sep: 8, Oct: 9, Nov: 10, Dec: 11};
  input = input.split(/[-\/]/);
  return new Date(input[2], input[1] in map? map[input[1]] : input[1]-1, input[0]);
}

document.write(parseDate('10-Jan-2016') + '<br>' + parseDate('10/1/2016'))
```

Though I'd make the month names lower case and use `map[input[1].toLowerCase()]` for greater compatibility (e.g. handle Feb, feb and FEB).

Comment: this code gives invalid date when the month is Jan . I tried changing the date 10-Jan-2016 and it gave Invalid Date

Comment: Ooops, sorry. For Jan, `map[input[1]]` returns 0 which is falsey so 'Jan' gets passed to the constructor. Fixed now.